# Placing content in Dropdown div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dropdown menu, for that I created a div and it's working fine but when I add the content on that div and then hover over it. The divs above the dropdown content div shifts.
How can I resolve this issue?
I don't want to have to use the position absolute.

Comment: We can't help without looking at your code

Comment: Please post your code so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to **reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].